# RTK Query: `await` when using `onQueryStarted` is not working

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, dispatch, rtk-query

I'm facing a strange problem.

I have an object inside my global state that needs to be populated with 3 different API endpoint calls.

So I choose to set one specific query with `onQueryStarted` method.
And make the 3 API calls together inside this method.

This are the `endpoints` from `api.ts` service:

```js
{
    scenario: builder.query({ query: ({theid}) => `scenarios/${scenarioId}`}),
    milestones: builder.query({ query: ({theid}) => `scenarios/${scenarioId}/ml`}),
    groups: builder.query({ query: ({theid}) => `scenarios/${scenarioId}/pg`}),

    setCurrentScenario: builder.query({
        query: id => `scenarios/${id}`, 
        async onQueryStarted (id, { dispatch, queryFulfilled, getState }) {
            try {
                let ml = await api.endpoints.milestones.initiate({theid: id})(dispatch, getState, "api")
                let pg = await api.endpoints.groups.initiate({theid: id})(dispatch, getState, "api")
                    
                let currentScen = await queryFulfilled
                dispatch( scenarioActions.addCurrentScenario( currentScen.data ))
                dispatch( scenarioActions.addCurrentScenarioMilestones( ml.data ))
                dispatch( scenarioActions.addCurrentScenarioPlayerGroups( pg.data ))
                    
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('ERRORE IN SETCURRENTSCENARIO: ', error)
            }
}
```

This works fine, **BUT** when I'm testing I need to add some "sleep" function, despite the fact that I `dispatch` the `setCurrentScenario` endpoint with an `await`:

```js
describe('A single Scenario should be fetched if user is manager', () => {
    it('should populate `current` scenario after asking with its `id`', async () => {

            // this populates `state.scenarios.current` 
            await store.dispatch( api.endpoints.setCurrentScenario.initiate( 1 ) )
            
            const sleep = (time:number) => new Promise((reslv) => setTimeout(reslv, time));
            await sleep(1000)

            const currentScenario = store.getState().scenarios.current
            console.log({currentScenario})

            expect(store.getState().scenarios.current?.name).not.toBeNull()
    })
})
```

I don't get it, why I need to sleep if I use `await` on that `store.dispatch()` ?

thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: Sidestepping the question for a second, you should dispatch `initiate`, not call it's return value.
`await dispatch(api.endpoints.milestones.initiate({theid: id}))`

Comment: I sware I tried that and it gave me an error telling me that "getState" wasn't a function... now I re-tried and it works O.o

Answer (score 0):

Because `await` means "do this and we continue executing our code later".

Other code - in this case, your test - can run in-between.
So your test has to finished until all the things are done and all the "later" code has executed, too.

Comment: So it's a "problem" related to the test suite and not to the store logic, right? 
Using the "sleep" could be a legit solution? 

Honestly I still don't get why it gives me this problem because I have a lot of test with `await` and they work fine. After await I use getState() and it give me the new state without errors. This problem only verifies when there is `onQueryStarted` involved.

Comment: Yeah, your sleep is legit, although it might wait a bit too long. Look into something like Testing Library's `waitFor`.